# Report Timeout when executing in SSDT

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I created SSRS Report in SSDT, the query executes fine in the Microsoft Sql server. But when executing the report it takes quite a while to load and shows the below error message:

> An error occurred during local report processing,
>    An error has
>   occurred during report processing,
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'dsSummary'.
>   Timeout expired,
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The wait operation timed out

Can anyone assist me with regards to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As apparent by the error message, it is a timeout issue. Here your first step should be to identify where exactly and why exactly it times out. To check that out, you need to query the table which keeps log of **anything** that happens once the report starts rendering. The table is `ExecutionLogStorage`. Depending on the [mode of deployment of SSRS](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/605912/SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-i), this table would be needed to be queried.

```
SELECT b.Name, A.* FROM 
ExecutionLog2  a
JOIN
[CATALOG] b ON a.ReportID = b.ItemID
and b.Name = <<Name of report>>
```

The column `AdditionalInfo` will give you a very nice picture of how the data sets fare up and how much time they take for execution. To know more about all the columns, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/248e5da9-e336-4ac4-a2fe-8279ef6b74e8/timedataretrieval-vs-timeprocessing-vs-timerendering).

Once you identify what is causing the issue(network/query/reporting server), you can go about fixing it.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reponse. Now may you please clarify to what catalog is in the sql query you used??.

Comment: CATALOG is a table in ReportServer database. Please go through the links in my answer to get clarity. If it helps you, please mark it as an answer.